# cocoa: suggestion about designing a cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm implementing a mac os program, but I have no idea about how to design a good application, such as how to design user interaction. If any book is about design a mac app or good design applications (like TweetDeck and sparrow are fresh design for me), please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html)

> Mac OS X Human Interface Guidelines describes the characteristics of
>   the OS X platform and the guidelines and principles that help you
>   design an outstanding user interface and user experience for your Mac
>   app.
>   Mac OS X Human Interface Guidelines does not describe how to implement
>   your designs in code.